# create a seperate interface project for both EJB and EJB Client in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ejb

This is what I did right now, when I create a EJB bean, I have to manually copy the interface.java to client project. This is really not a good idea when you make a change to your interface. So I am thinking I should create a seperate interface project for both EJB and EJB client. In eclipse, how can i do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate Java project and put the interface(s) in there. Then you can have your EJB and client projects depend on that one. Depending on what you use to do your builds (Ant, Maven, etc) you'll need to do some work to make sure things are built correctly.

Comment: I found the problems in my project. I have to include ALL the projects in one Enterprise Application Project. and deploy the Enterprise Application project into app server.